# Сохранение данных в json-файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, парсер, save

Как сохранить результат парсинга в json файл

```py
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


FILE = 'games.csv'
HOST = 'https://store.steampowered.com'
URL = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/ru/Гонки/?l=russian'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 YaBrowser/20.11.3.183 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return req


def get_conten(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_='tab_item')
    games = []

    for item in items:
        ru_price = item.find('div', class_='discount_final_price')
        if ru_price:
            ru_price = ru_price.get_text()
        else:
            ru_price = 'Цена неизвестна'
        games.append(
            {
                'title': item.find('div', class_='tab_item_name').get_text(strip=True),
                'tag': item.find('div', class_='tab_item_top_tags').get_text(strip=True),
                'ru_price': ru_price,
            }
        )
    return games
  
 
def parser():
    PAGENATION= input('Укажите количество страниц для парсинга: ')
    PAGENATION= int(PAGENATION.strip())
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        games = []
        for page in range(0, PAGENATION):
            print(f'Парсинг страницы {page}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'p': page})
            games.extend(get_content(html.text))
        print(games)
    else:
        print('Error')


parser()
```

Comment: и все-таки: в .csv или в .json?

Comment: не обращайте внимание на некоторые строки в коде, связанные с csv, надо в .json сохранить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из `def parser()` возвращайте список словарей:

```
def parser():
    PAGENATION= input('Укажите количество страниц для парсинга: ')
    PAGENATION= int(PAGENATION.strip())
    html = get_html(URL)
    
    games = []
    if html.status_code == 200:
        for page in range(0, PAGENATION):
            print(f'Парсинг страницы {page}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'p': page})
            games.extend(get_content(html.text))
        print(games)
    else:
        print('Error')

    return games
```

присвойте вернувшийся словарь:

```
data = parser()
```

и сохраняйте как-то так:

```
import json

FILE_JSON = 'games.json'

with open(FILE_JSON, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump({'data': data}, outfile)
```

в результате - файл `games.json` с данными...